# Question related to constraints & limitations of Amazon accounts across regions?

Tags: discussion, scope

Please highlight how this is too broad and/ or could be made to go your way. I've pointed to such issues with Apple App Store ID's and accounts and widely written about issues with them. There's many articles on that subject but not much about Amazon accounts.

[What are Pros & cons of using Login ID w same email address or different ones, when having Amazon accounts in multiple regions US, UK, India etc](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118322/what-are-pros-cons-of-using-login-id-w-same-email-address-or-different-ones-w)

Comment: Alex, the question lacks focus and would be hard to answer succinctly.  That's what makes it too broad.  However, even if the question weren't too broad, we're more about *using* web apps than policies and procedures of particular websites.  I'm not sure where on SE this would be on-topic, if anywhere.

Comment: @jonsca - The workings of "Web Apps" are governed by the underlying business rules embededed in the system code. My usage and web-app experience is constrained by these rules & policies. If you try to sign up for a website that wont let you sign up without meeting XYZ constraints of a password, thats the user experience based on their policy; sometimes well stated up front, other times hidden and not very obvious or visible in its workings of WHY such and such. I will think about how to reframe and rephrase the question in this week.

Comment: @jonsca I hope you get what I am trying to say. When we sign up for any site there are TOS agreements etc which restrict users and allow operator to  make things work X way or change the workings in Y way. 

Thought not easy to decipher, but this https://www.amazon.in/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201248840
will LIMIT my usage of the site & its features due to their policy applying constraints on my "paid" usage

Comment: @jonsca - There was a time 4 members could be added to an Amazon prime account as family or dwelling members. We could do that as users and then one day we were unable to DO SO on the web usage experience. Then the underlying TOS that caused the "web usage" experience change was that now only 2 members or adults could be on it, while other 2 or so would have to be dependents and not able to operate fully in their web experience as before. Granfathered members could continue with old experience, while newer account members had different experience. We cant decipher experience issues w/o knowing

Answer (score 4):

> What are Pros & cons of using Login ID w same email address or different ones, when having Amazon accounts in multiple regions US, UK, India etc

The above was used both on the question title and body. It makes the question too broad because it encompases two scenarios:

> same email address or different ones

Also it also encompases a broad list of countries

> multiple regions US, UK, India etc.

By the other hand, including links to questions on Ask Different SE, regardless that they have a 0 score and answers with low score doesn't make the question specific and on-topic on Web Applications.

Questions should include on themselves all the required information to respond the question.

The question doesn't mention if you already have Amazon accounts in multiple regions nor if you already faced a specific problem.

Comment: I do have multiple accounts across US, India and UK. And I am concerned based on the issues I've read about and faced with Apple Stores.. similar copyright & purchase carryover boundaries & limits exist in amazon as well (as linked). I'd like to circumvent buying things and then RUN into issues after a while and find boom.. wasted money. Pre-CAUTION.. Prevention is better than No Cure.

Comment: I tend tend to keep copies of the Question with Subject & Body in notepad / editors so its a one time copy and paste. So subject/ heading is included in body and duplicated - Is that such a crime? 

I am not talking Amazon DE. I am talking Amazon US, India primarily and little bit of UK. 

Should I update it with the fact that I have Amazon US, India and UK accounts and am concerned about how Amazon policies / website will behave